# Get directions between multiple coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit

I would like to get a unique direction between many coordinate (lat,long).
For example I have an API get request that return me 200 coordinate, and I have to create a unique direction between al of this 200 point in map.
How can I do that (the array of 200 point is ordered by math distance).
Example:

```
[9.6247279999999993, 46.170966100000001]
[9.6244014, 46.171050399999999]
[9.6240834999999993, 46.171273900000003]
[9.6240570000000005, 46.171284999999997]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties :-

```
var mapView: MKMapView!
var polyLine: MKPolyline!
var lineView: MKPolylineView!
```

Create coordinate array from latitude and langitude:

```
  var coordinateArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
for obj in arrayOfLatlong {
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, lon1); 
coordinateArray.append(coordinate)
 }
```

// add polyline: -

```
 polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinateArray, count: coordinateArray.count)
 mapView?.visibleMapRect = polyLine.boundingMapRect
//If you want the route to be visible
 mapView?.add(polyLine)
```

and in delegate method:-

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> 
  MKOverlayView {
if overlay == polyLine {
    if lineView == nil {
        lineView = MKPolylineView(polyline: routeLine)
        lineView.fillColor = UIColor.red
        lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        lineView.lineWidth = 5
    }
    return lineView
}
return nil
```

}

**create a walkable path:-**

```
   // Source
     let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: 
  long)
     let placemark: MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
      let source =  MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

   //Destination
    let destination =  MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

    let request:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = source
    request.destination = destination
    // Specify the transportation type
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.walking;

    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate (completionHandler: {
        (response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            let directionsResponse = response
            // Get whichever currentRoute you'd like, ex. 0
       self.arrayOfRoutes =  directionsResponse?.routes
        }
    } as! MKDirectionsHandler)
```

get route from arrayOfRoutes and show on mapview.

```
mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
```

Comment: I don't wanna create a line but a walkable path

Answer (score 0):

You can create a path by using `GMSPolyline` and `GMSMutablePath`.

Add all of your locations to another `NSMutableArray` named as `allLocations`

And then use following code

```
 GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
 for (NSArray *eachLocation in allLocations){
       NSString *latitude = [eachLocation objectAtIndex:1];
       NSString *longitude = [eachLocation objectAtIndex:0];
      [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude.doubleValue,longitude.doubleValue)];
 }
       rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
       rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.5f;
       rectangle.map = self.mapView;
```

Where rectangle is `GMSPolyline` created as global, so that you can remove that path if you want. And `mapView` is object for `GMSMapView`.

Comment: I don't wanna create a line but a walkable path